# Understanding ~ Operator

Tags: operators, bit-manipulation

I am learning Bitwise Operators and for that I pulled out an [article](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/understanding-bitwise-operators--active-11301) on tutsplus. Well, it is written quite nicely. I could understand the `&` and `|` operator but the `~` is messing things up. For example, as stated there in the article:

> In fact, just as ! flips a boolean from true to false or vice versa,
>   the ~ operator reverses each binary digit in an integer: from 0 to 1
>   and 1 to 0.

The article has assumed that the OS is storing integer as `1 byte`or `8 bits`. I am following it. I am using PHP for experimenting. The code's below:

```
$b = 12;
$NOR = ~$b;

/*
* ------------------------
* | $b | 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 | = 12
* ------------------------
* |  ~ | 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 | = 243 as 1 + 2 + 16 + 32 + 64 + 128 = 243
* ------------------------
* Each digit will be inverted.
*/

echobr($NOR);
```

Even if we consider that `$b`was stored as `32 bit`. Then the inverted value should be `> 243`. Instead, it returns `-13`. `echobr()` is the function I defined.

If it can be explained, it will be very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$b = 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1100

~$b = 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 0011 = -13

Note that PHP uses the [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation which means that the most significant bit is the sign bit, here '1' refers to '-'. You can read more about the sign bit here [Sign bit-Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_bit).

As a matter of fact, for any signed integer in PHP, -$i == ~$i + 1

Comment: This is true for nearly every machine out there, but to be technically correct, you should mention that this assumes 2's complement. There are other possible representations where `-i` is not necessarily `~i+1`. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves thankfully, PHP always uses two's complement. That's about the only thing it got right though..

Comment: @harold Hah. I had no idea. I don't do any PHP programming and I don't know the language. It's nice to know, thanks for jumping in.